# bind passes null when trying to pass it from select tag

Tags: c#, .net, blazor

I'm trying to insert data to a table which has a foreign key in it. I've put the categories in a select tag, shows them correctly, but when I try to pass that ID string to `SelectedSubCatCategory`, it shows up as null.

```
<select @bind="SelectedSubCatCategory">           
  @foreach (var item in category_items)
  {
    <option value="@item.Cat_ID" >@item.Cat_Name </option>
  }
</select>
```

```
string SelectedSubCatCategory;
protected async Task SubCategoryInsert()
{
  Guid guid = Guid.NewGuid();
  string SubCatGUID = guid.ToString();

  var category = await categoryService.GetEntryByIdAsync(SelectedSubCatCategory);
  SubCategory sc = new SubCategory()
  {
    SCat_ID = SubCatGUID,
    SCat_Cat = category,
    SCat_Name = SelectedSubCatName
  };
  await subCategoryService.InsertEntryAsync(sc);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out on my own:

You have to have an @onchange event instead of @bind

```
<select @onchange="SetSelectedSubCatCategory">         
  <option> Please select </option> // default option  
  @foreach (var item in category_items)
  {
    <option value="@item.Cat_ID" >@item.Cat_Name </option>
  }
</select>
```

And then this little code will do the rest

```
void SetSelectedSubCatCategory(ChangeEventArgs e)
{
  SelectedSubCatCategory = e.Value.ToString();
}
```

gg ez